# TypeScript debugging with Web Essentials and bundling not working

Tags: debugging, typescript, web-essentials

I am running TypeScript 8.3.1 with web essentials 2.5.1, IE 10 and Visual Studio 2012.  I have an app where all my ts code sits in an app folder.  I have set a web essentials bundle up of that folder and the map files are all being generated.

When I look at the output of the bundled Js it has all the source mappings in there.  A snippet of it below.

```
///#source 1 1 /app/controllers/featured-carousel-controller.js

(my code sits here)

//@ sourceMappingURL=featured-carousel-controller.js.map
```

However I cannot seem to get TypeScript debugging working with this model. If I create a new Visual Studio project it debugs fine out of the box but not with this bundling. I noticed the `sourceMappingURL` does not include the folder path like the JS file does.  Is that correct?

I have checked to make sure the bundled.js is in my default.html and the app works fine.  Can anyone think of anything else I may need to do?

Comment: I'm not sure source maps are intended to work when the script has been bundled. My understanding was that bundling is intended for release, not debug (at least that is the suggestion here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: It worked for me with a Debug compile and the installed component mentione dbelow.

Comment: I just got to the point where I reinstalled visual studio. Without resharper or anything. But still. Typescript can only be debugged when the js and map-file are included in the poject. Madness!

Answer (score 1):

They removed some stuff from WebEssentials and rolled it into WebTools 2012.2

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update

download:

https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/ASPDOTNETandWebTools2012_2.appids

I recall not having this functionality in VS2013 Pro, which I have at home. Now I wonder what that needs to get the same to work in that edition. If you know, please tell me.

Update 2:

Sheet....It worked for about a minute then it is telling me there are no symbols to break on.